# Access job parameters in job bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm defining a job bean in my spring batch configuration file as:

```
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
```

I want to name the job dynamically, based on the jobParameters passed while launching the job.
I'm trying to achieve something like `jobBuilderFactory.get(jobNameFromJobParams)`.
I know the job is defined at the configuration time and the parameters are passed at the runtime.
Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Job parameters are typically used for properties that vary between different instances of the same job (often to identify job instances). In your case, the job name will be the same for all job instances, so I believe a system property is more appropriate than a job parameter for that. Here is a quick example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps,
                   @Value("${jobName:myDefaultJobName}") String jobName) {
        return jobs.get(jobName)
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("hello world");
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        })
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("jobName", "foo");
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfig.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=foo]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
[main] INFO org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [step]
hello world
[main] INFO org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Step: [step] executed in 31ms
[main] INFO org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=foo]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 57ms
```

You can pass the job name dynamically when you launch the job with `-DjobName=dynamicJobName`

**EDIT**: Add example of how to launch the job from a web controller

```
@RestController
public class JobLaunchingController {

   @Autowired
   private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
   public void launch(@RequestParam("jobName") String jobName) throws Exception {
      Job job = context.getBean(jobName, Job.class);
      jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
   }


}
```

Comment: I'm launching the job triggering from controller endpoint.

Comment: That's not an issue. Where is the dynamic name coming from? A request parameter, a servlet context parameter?

Comment: As a request parameter.

Comment: ok the job name is dynamic, but I guess you have a limited number of jobs defined in your application, which you can get by name. So in this case, you can get the job name from the request parameter and get the job from the application context by name. I updated the answer with an example.